# Convertig an image to an .ICO file without loosing color depth (and without installing additional utilities)?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, image, icons

In a form I have an `ImageList` named `MainLogoImageList` containing a 100x100 pixel 32-bit colordepth image. That is my app logo.

I am too lazy to set up an icon editor and edit an icon of that logo, or convert the image to an .ICO file. (Ergh, well, I am not allowed to install custom utilities.)

To set my forms' icon, I use

```
Icon = IconFromImage(MainLogoImageList.Images(0))
```

in the `OnLoad` event handler to set the window icon.

In my about box, i have a `PictureBox` with no image. In its `OnLoad` event, I use

```
LogoPictureBox.Image = MyMainForm.MainLogoImageList.Images(0)
Icon = IconFromImage(MyMainForm.MainLogoImageList.Images(0))
```

to set the About box's icon and content.

So far, so good, the icon looks pretty good for a being created from a 100x100 pixel bitmap.

**Is there an easy "no utility required" :-) way to get the icon that is returned my `IconFromImage` saved into an .ICO file so that it will keep the color depth when loaded as the app icon?** I want to use exactly the icon that `IconFromImage` creates.

Saving it using

```
Dim S As New FileStream("MyAppIcon.ico", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write)
Icon.Save(S)
S.Close()
```

in the main form's `OnLoad` event handler and loading that .ICO file as the app icon in VS's project properties dialog yields and icon that is obviously converted to 16 colors, and looks awful.

This is VB 10 Express.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this, nor would you want to maintain code like this.  Take the file home, convert it.

Comment: @Hans Passant why not make this an answer so I can accept it. Maybe some other lazy :) guy wonders about the same and finds this answer useful.

Comment: I dunno, what really only matters here is how *you* solved this problem.  Don't hesitate to post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: After finding the best answer myself so many times on SO, I hesitated to do what you suggest. But -- will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Followed the wise advide to take this home, edit and convert it there.

Gimp@home at work.

Worked fine, looks great.

A codeless solution is better than no solution at all :-)